# Change image_intro path

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to override the **layouts/joomla/content/intro_image**, so that the intro image will have a different path than the Joomla original path.

More specifically, I want to add `thumbnail` to the file path as the directory before the filename and prepend `thumbnail_` to the filename.

So, an image with the path
`/images/news/football.jpg` would become
`/images/news/thumbnail/thumbnail_football.jpg`

The code that shows the image is:

```
<?php $images = json_decode($displayData->images); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the thumbnail on the fly. You can check for this here: https://phproberto.com/es/36-create-thumbnails-on-the-fly-for-joomla-content-articles